# Rails view is viewing too much data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, haml

I have such RoR view (on haml):

```
-if @articles.blank?
  %h3
    Увы, нет артикулов в данной категории

-else
  - @constr_num.each do |cc|
    = cc.ARL_SEARCH_NUMBER 
  %table.zebra
    %tr
      %th Производитель
      %th Наименование/описание
      %th    
      %th Цена
      %th Кол-во на складе
      %th Сроки поставки
      %th
    -if @non_original.present?
      %br
      - if @non_original.is_a?(Array)
        =@non_original.each do |no|
          %tr{ :class => cycle("zebra-stripe zebra-green zebra1", "zebra-stripe zebra-green zebra2")}   
            %td
              %h4
                =no.brand
            %td
              %h4
                -if user_signed_in?
                  = no.article_nr
                -else
                  = no.article_nr.first.concat("***").concat(no.article_nr.last)    
              =no.description
            %td
              = #link_to "подробнее/аналоги", "#"
            %td
              =no.price
            %td
              =no.quantity.gsub(/[^0-9]/, '').to_i
            %td
              =no.waittime
            %td
              -if no.quantity.present? && no.quantity.gsub(/[^0-9]/, '').to_i > 0  
                = #button_to 'В корзину', line_items_path(ART_ID: no), :remote => false, :class => "to-cart"    
                = #button_to 'В корзину2', line_items_path(ART: no.brand+" | "+no.article_nr+" | "+no.description, price: 11, distributor_id: no.distributor_id), :remote => false, :class => "to-cart" 
              = form_tag(line_items_path) do |f|
                = hidden_field_tag 'ART', no.brand+" | "+no.article_nr+" | "+no.description
                = #text_field_tag 'price', 11
                = hidden_field_tag 'price', no.price
                = hidden_field_tag 'distributor_id', no.distributor_id
                = submit_tag "Upload", :class => "to-cart"       

    %br
    - @articles.each do |art|
      %tr{ :class => cycle("zebra-stripe zebra-grey zebra1", "zebra-stripe zebra-grey zebra2")}       
        %td
          %h4
            = art.supplier.SUP_BRAND
            =# art.ART_ID
        %td
          = art.art_name
          %h4
            -if user_signed_in?
              = art.ART_ARTICLE_NR
            -else
              = art.ART_ARTICLE_NR.first.concat("***").concat(art.ART_ARTICLE_NR.last)    
        %td 
          = link_to "подробнее/аналоги", art
        %td
          -if art.Quantity.present? && art.Quantity > 0
            = #((art.Price.to_f - art.Price.to_f * @discont) * @eur_cur.currency_value).round(-1)
          %h4
            = #art.find_price(art.ART_ARTICLE_NR.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, ''), art.supplier.SUP_BRAND, "price")
          %p{ :nr => art.ART_ARTICLE_NR.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, ''), :br => art.supplier.SUP_BRAND, :type => "price", :class => "priceclass", :id => art.ART_ARTICLE_NR.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, '')}
        %td
          %p{ :nr => art.ART_ARTICLE_NR.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, ''), :br => art.supplier.SUP_BRAND, :type => "quantity", :class => "qntclass", :id => art.ART_ARTICLE_NR.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, '').concat("q")}
        .logo

        %td
          %p{ :nr => art.ART_ARTICLE_NR.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, ''), :br => art.supplier.SUP_BRAND, :type => "waittime", :class => "waittimeclass", :id => art.ART_ARTICLE_NR.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, '').concat("w")}
        %td
          -if art.Quantity.present? && art.Quantity > 0  
            = #button_to 'В корзину', line_items_path(ART: art.supplier.SUP_BRAND+" | "+art.ART_ARTICLE_NR+" | "+art.art_name, price: 11), :remote => false, :class => "to-cart"
          = form_tag(line_items_path) do |f|
            = hidden_field_tag 'ART', art.supplier.SUP_BRAND+" | "+art.ART_ARTICLE_NR+" | "+art.art_name
            = #text_field_tag 'price', 11
            = hidden_field_tag 'price', 0, :id => art.ART_ARTICLE_NR.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, '')
            = hidden_field_tag 'distributor_id', 1
            = submit_tag "Upload", :class => "to-cart"
    - if @oem_art.is_a?(Array)
      =@oem_art.each do |oem|
        %tr{ :class => cycle("zebra-stripe zebra-blue zebra1", "zebra-stripe zebra-blue zebra2")}   
          %td
            %h4
              =#oem[oem][:car]


  .pagination_content
    = paginate @articles  
  %h4
    Не нашли необходимую запчасть?
  = link_to "Сделать on-line запрос менеджеру", new_ask_vin_path
```

I think that I must see normal table, but I get first `=@non_original.each do |no|` like

```
[#<PriceList id: 77845, distributor_id: 1, brand: "TECH-AS", article_nr: "110064Q", price: 3.0, quantity: ">8", waittime: 1, description: "110064Q (TO1341D) OX143D 1100696 AUDI/VW TDI", created_at: "2012-10-11 21:21:56", updated_at: "2012-10-11 21:21:56">, #<PriceList id: 7253, distributor_id: 1, brand: "CARGO", article_nr: "B140036", price: 0.0, quantity: "0", waittime: 1, description: "140036A 3471553 Del 12.08x14.08x14.00", created_at: "2012-10-11 09:36:26", updated_at: "2012-10-11 09:36:26">]
```

But then I see this data in table... This is magic) how can I see this data only in table?

See screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Also my controller looks like this:

```
def get_parts_via_category
    *****(secret))))
    @articles = Kaminari.paginate_array(@pre_articles).page(params[:page]).per(20)

    @asdasd = ArtLookup.get_construction_number(@pre_articles.map(&:ART_ID))
    @constr_num = @asdasd.uniq{|x| x.ARL_SEARCH_NUMBER}
    logger.warn("mE gusta !!!!!!")
    non_original = []
    @pre_articles.each do |a|
      logger.warn("SDFSDFS fsdf sdf sdfSDF SDF SD !!!!!!!!!!! dgfdfg d*fd*g fd-gd f")
      a.logger.warn(a.supplier.SUP_BRAND.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, ''))
      norig = get_non_tecdoc(a.ART_ARTICLE_NR.to_s.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, ''), 1, a.supplier.SUP_BRAND)
      if norig.present?
        non_original << norig
      end      
    end

    oem_art = []
    @constr_num.each do |o|
      as_oem = get_from_as_oem(o.ARL_SEARCH_NUMBER)
      if as_oem.present?
        oem_art << as_oem
      end
    end    
    @non_original = non_original.uniq
    @oem_art = oem_art.to_a.uniq


    @eur_cur = Currency.find_by_currency_name("EUR")
      @discont = 0
    if user_signed_in?
      @discont = 0.01
      user = User.find(current_user.id)
      @total = 0
      for order in user.orders do
        @total += order.totalcost
        if @total >=0 && @total <= 1000000
          @discont = 0.02
        end
        if @total >=1000000 && @total < 7000000
          @discont = 0.1
        end
        if @total >=7000000 && @total < 10000000
          @discont = 0.15
        end
        if @total >=10000000
          @discont = 0.2
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Try replacing `=` to `-` here: `=@non_original.each do |no|`

Comment: @jdoe hm, good idea... write it as answer... also what is difference between - and = if we say with simple language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line:

```
=@non_original.each do |no|
```

has to start with `-` sign:

```
-@non_original.each do |no|
```

This way you'll *hide the result of `each` method*, which returns the array itself if you pass a block(`do ... end` or `{ ... }`):

```
[1,2,3].each{} # => [1, 2, 3]
```